# Assets is already defined as object Assets

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am doing more extended tests for Play Subproject feature as described here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SBTSubProjects. But I am getting the error:

```
Assets is already defined as object Assets
```

Sample application hosted on github: https://github.com/adis-me/PlayStrap

I have defined an Asset controller for my subprojects as described here: [Asset Controller description](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/documentation/manual/detailledTopics/build/SBTSubProjects.md#assets-and-controller-classes-should-be-all-defined-in-the-controllersadmin-package), even for the main project, but the error keeps popping up. What is wrong with my project?

**Controller**

```
package com.company.playstrap.controllers;

import controllers.AssetsBuilder;

public class Assets {

    public static controllers.AssetsBuilder delegate = new AssetsBuilder();

}
```

**Routes file**

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                               com.company.playstrap.controllers.Application.index()

# Include sub projects
-> /common                              common.Routes
-> /admin                               admin.Routes
-> /website                             website.Routes

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file                   com.company.playstrap.controllers.Assets.delegates.at(path="/public", file)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a known bug: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/2Zk5wjAlIng/Jcec1lt7AzQJ

My workaround for an own admin module:

```
package controllers.admin;
import controllers.AssetsBuilder;
import play.api.mvc.AnyContent;
import play.api.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    private static AssetsBuilder delegate = new AssetsBuilder();

    public static Action<AnyContent> asset(String path, String file) {
        return delegate.at(path, file);
    }

}

//routes file
GET /assets/*file   controllers.admin.Application.asset(path="/public", file)
```

Comment: This means that all (reversed routing stuff) in views needs to be written as: `@routes.Assets.asset("someAss")`? Is this bug yet fixed, I cannot find any bug report for this issue...

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem last week when I was trying to write the Assets class as a Java class. I could solve the compilation problem writing the Assets class in my submodule as a Scala class, the same way as described on the docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/SBTSubProjects

Basically, my project's structure is:

```
MyApplication
  | - app
  | - conf
  | - modules
        | - admin
            | - app
                | - controllers
                    | - admin
                        | - Assets.scala
  | - project
  | - public
```

**Assets.scala** content:

```
package controllers.contabil

object Assets extends controllers.AssetsBuilder
```

And finally, the content of my **admin.routes** file is:

```
GET     /assets/*file    controllers.admin.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

# Home page
GET     /index           controllers.admin.Application.index()
```

Cheers