# Assets is already defined as object Assets play framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

I get this compilation error and although i've searched everywhere i can't find a solution that works for me. My routes file is pretty simple:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /greekblogportal/                           controllers.Blogs.list()
GET     /greekblogportal/login                      controllers.Blogs.login()
GET     /greekblogportal/logout                     controllers.Blogs.logout()
GET     /greekblogportal/blogs/new                  controllers.Blogs.newBlog()
GET     /greekblogportal/blogs/:id                  controllers.Blogs.details(id: models.Blog)
GET     /greekblogportal/blogpicture/:id            controllers.Blogs.picture(id: String)
GET     /greekblogportal/blogfavore/:id             controllers.Blogs.favore(id: Long, username: String ?= null)
POST    /greekblogportal/login                      controllers.Blogs.authenticate()
POST    /greekblogportal/blogs/                     controllers.Blogs.save
DELETE  /greekblogportal/blogs/:id                  controllers.Blogs.delete(id: Long)
GET     /greekblogportal/categories/new             controllers.Categories.newCategory()
GET     /greekblogportal/categories/:id             controllers.Categories.details(id: models.Category)
GET     /greekblogportal/categories/                controllers.Categories.list()
GET     /greekblogportal/categorypicture/:id        controllers.Categories.picture(id: String)
POST    /greekblogportal/categories/                controllers.Categories.save()
DELETE  /greekblogportal/categories/:id             controllers.Categories.delete(id: Long)
GET     /greekblogportal/users/new                  controllers.Users.newUser()
GET     /greekblogportal/users/:id                  controllers.Users.details(id: models.User)
GET     /greekblogportal/userpicture/:id            controllers.Users.picture(id: String)
GET     /greekblogportal/users/                     controllers.Users.list()
POST    /greekblogportal/users/                     controllers.Users.save()
DELETE  /greekblogportal/users/:id                  controllers.Users.delete(id: Long)
POST    /greekblogportal/search/                    controllers.SearchTags.search()
GET     /greekblogportal/passChangeForm             controllers.Users.changePassForm()
POST    /greekblogportal/passChange                 controllers.Users.changePass()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

I have never changed anything as far as the Assets are concerned. Anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Full stack trace:

```
    2014-09-08 13:02:00,216 - [ERROR] - from application in New I/O worker #2 


! @6jenc97af - Internal server error, for (GET) [/greekblogportal/] ->

play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[Assets is already defined as object Assets]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(PlayReloader.scala:298) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2.apply(PlayReloader.scala:298) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2.apply(PlayReloader.scala:296) ~[na:na]
    at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1.reload(PlayReloader.scala:296) ~[na:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104) ~[play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:102) ~[play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762484/assets-is-already-defined-as-object-assets

Comment: I have checked that link from stackoverflow, done what it said but the problem remains.. Full stacktrace added.