# company is already defined as object company error in play framework 2.2.1

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I am working on a project in play. It was working fine but when I added a new controller called CompanyController, it gave me a compilation error `company is already defined as object company` in my view.

CompanyController:

```
public static Result login() {
    return ok(views.html.admin.company.login.render("Your new application is ready."));
}
```

Routes file:

```
GET    /company/login    controllers.companypac.CompanyController.login()

GET    /assets/*file     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

I cant figure out why this problem is occurring?

Searching for the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15765800/3841803) didn't yield any resolution of the problem.

Note: The above routes are part of my routes file and do not contain all routes.

Comment: It's very hard to understand the problem from that information. Where does the error happen exactly, what file?

Comment: this error occured in my view.But this problem is solved now by changing the directory of my view .I am still trying to figure out why this problem occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason why this problem existed was because your SBT didn't get the chance to recompile your views. You said that changing your the directory to your view changed the problem which probably triggered SBT into recompiling your views.

I've had similar issues regarding this and most of them disappeared after a recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by changing the directoty of my view .I dont know what exactly the problem is maybe that SBT dint get the chance to recompile the views as said by @Martin.