# Assets Controller Compilation error[value Asset is not a member of object controllers.Assets] Play 2.3.8

Tags: playframework, compilation, migration, assets, typesafe-activator

I got a problem after migrating my play framework project from 2.2.4 to 2.3.8:

This is the error output running the command "activator compile":

```
[error] ...\workspace\testproject\conf\routes: value Asset is not a member of object controllers.Assets 
[error] bad symbolic reference to controllers.Assets.Asset encountered in class file 'JavascriptLitteral.class'.
[error] Cannot access type Asset in object controllers.Assets. The current classpath may be missing a definition for controllers.Assets.Asset, or JavascriptLitteral.class may have been compiled against a version that's incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[error] ...\workspace\testproject\conf\routes: value Asset is not a member of object controllers.Assets 
[error] three errors found
```

I wrote my own Assets Controller, which I created because of a sub-project. This project is not included anymore, thus the controller.Assets still is.

The routes path is the standard:

```
GET  /assets/*file       controllers.Assets.at(path="public", file)
```

Could it be, that Activator for 2.3.8 and Play 2.2.4 compile stuff differently / cleaning the project differently? I tried to switch off eclipse's build automatically, still no difference :(.

Does Anybody have an idea, what this problem creates? I am happy about any hints :D

Comment: did you solved the problem ?

Comment: I had the same issue for a project with sub-projects (Play 2.3.8). I also created Assets objects for all the sub-projects as described in the documentation. My mistake was that I also created an Assets object for the root project. It led to the same error you describes. I removed it and everything compiles.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `object Assets extends controllers.AssetsBuilder` in another file and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Making my methods static did the trick, eg.

```
 public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Now I work."));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `activator clean` first, then run `activator run` should work. If it doesn't work, it's probably because `activator clean` did not cleanup your out-dated generated routes somehow(that should be a bug of activator). Just manually remove the generated routes, it should work,

`rm target/scala-2.11/routes/main/router/*`

The path may differ depending on the version of play you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the path you are defineing in route.Try

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

with `path="/public"`

If the above dint solve your problem then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15765800/3841803).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `path=` when writing down the question (I correct that), but it is included in the original route file. Regarding the link: my problem is not **Assets is already defined as object Assets** but **value Asset is not a member of object controllers.Assets**

Comment: @Knut play is still reading the old Asset instead of Assets did you remove old path in routes and did you clean

Comment: I did.. I cleaned, I cleaned in every combination with the commands: compile, eclipse, reload, update,  I rewrote the route file, I rewrote the Assets controller, I tried nearly every combination in build.sbt (different scala versions) and plugins.sbt. Now I am concidering to rewrite the project. I also cannot find the JavascriptLitteral.com file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if activator (play 2.3.8) is using a different library dependency source repo %USER_HOME%/.ivy2 or something like that, thus the project created under 2.2.4 is not getting updated. which is bad. even not by commands activator clean activator reload and so on... does anybody have a clue why? I hoped that "activator eclipse" will do the job, but It is stopping when the compiler finds errors

Comment: did you remove `play 2.2` and set the new `play 2.3` path.Also can you post your `build.sbt`